# Как организовать работу с сессиями пользователя в Telegram боте?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, сессия

Появилась задача написать Telegram бота, вроде все шло хорошо. Но есть не понятные вопросы, без очевидного решения:

1. Как организовать работу с сессиями пользователя?
2. Как сделать обрыв сессии пользователя, если ее нет в явном виде? Где то на форуме вычитал что идентификатором сессии является идентификатор пользователя который начал общение с ботом, на ум приходит написать костыль для такой сессии.

Comment: Что именно имеется ввиду под сессиями? Вопрос непонятен. Если нужно просто отслеживать начало и конец общения - ну сделай первое сообщение началом. А если человек не пишет более 20 минут - то это конец сессии. И так по кругу.

Comment: это и подразумевал, только придется писать свой механизм для работы с такими сессиями. В API Telegrama походу такого механизма нету.

Comment: А для чего там подобны механизм сессии вообще в АПИ должен быть? Он же бессмысленный в рамках его АПИ

Comment: @Andrew, почему бессмысленный, а если я хочу сделать сохранение сессии и т.д